# Looping through all divs in a div (including children)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, each

I had the static version of this page working great locally but the CMS my company use spits out horrible code when it's implemented into the CMS.

Originally I was trying to loops through all divs within a div and build a select box with the results.

```
<div id="products-list">
  <div id="glasgow">
      <div class="product">
        <!--Content-->
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="edinburgh">
      <div class="product">
        <!--Content-->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using a simple for each loop with first level divs was fine.

```
 $("#products-list > div").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") != undefined || $(this).attr("id") != null) {
            $('#select-example').append($('<option>', {
                value: $(this).attr("id"),
                text: $(this).attr("id")
            }));
        }
    });
```

However my CMS decides to wrap the divs like this, and there is not much I can do about it. I'm trying to return the IDs "Glasgow" and "Edinbugh".

```
<div id="products-list">
  <div class="w-component-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="w-component-content">
        <div id="glasgow">
          <div class="product">
            <!-- Content --> 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-component-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="w-component-content">
        <div id="edinburgh">
          <div class="product">
            <!-- Content --> 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Most likely is something minor and I just need another set of eyes. Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply filter div by using attribute selector,

```js
$("#products-list  div[id]").each(function() {
  $('#select-example').append($('<option>', {
    value: $(this).attr("id"),
    text: $(this).attr("id")
  }));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products-list">
  <div class="w-component-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="w-component-content">
        <div id="glasgow">
          <div class="product">
            <!-- Content -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-component-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="w-component-content">
        <div id="edinburgh">
          <div class="product">
            <!-- Content -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<select id="select-example"></select>
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew it was something so simple. I'll mark as correct when I can (you were too quick). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Pranav's answer, you can also do ti like this.

```
$("#products-list > div > div:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
  $('#select-example').append($('<option>', {
    value: $(this).attr("id"),
    text: $(this).attr("id")
  }));

});
```

the `nth-child` allows you to select a particular child inside an HTML element. It is generally used in CSS, but works perfectly with Javascript for such purposes.

For more detail, refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: This is interesting too, never thought about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your HTML, if it conforms to the following assumption

- Desired element is always the parent of an element with class `product`

you can do this. (Output in browser console)

```js
function getCityIds() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('.product'),
    list = Array.prototype.slice.call(list),
    value = [];

  list.forEach(function(elem) {
    value.push(elem.parentNode.id);
  });

  return value;
}

function appendOptions(element, options) {
  options.forEach(function(elem) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = elem;
    option.text = elem;
    element.appendChild(option);
  });
}

appendOptions(document.getElementById('example'), getCityIds());
```

```html
<div id="products-list">
  <div class="w-component-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="w-component-content">
        <div id="glasgow">
          <div class="product">
            <!-- Content -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-component-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="w-component-content">
        <div id="edinburgh">
          <div class="product">
            <!-- Content -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<select id="example"></select>
```